# Mobx set an observable from socket

Tags: sockets, observable, mobx

I am using sockets to pipe data to my project with a node server in the backend. I can configure my store correctly, but when I do the following:

```
class Store {
    @observable
    socketData = {};

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io("localhost:5000");
        this.socket.on("event", function(data) {
            this.socketData = data;
        });
    }
}
```

when I console.log(this.socketData) the data, it prints out a proxy instead of the JSON data I passed through from the socket. When I console.log(data) in the constructor, it prints out the object. Is there a reason why my data prints out as a proxy? Or is this a bad way to setup the observable with sockets?

Answer (score 1):

MobX replaces your original data object with a proxy to be able to detect property access and modification.
Most of the time this is completely transparent and you don't need to be aware you are dealing with a proxy, but if you really need a plain JavaScript object, you can use `mobx.toJS`:

```
console.log(mobx.toJS(this.socketData))
```

Additionally, in your constructor you might want to change `function(data) {...}` to an arrow function `data => {...}` to make sure `this` refers to your store in the function body.